# Robot Framework: "Library" not found

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, robotframework

My very first script in Robot with PyCharm tells me the following error message:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Desktop\MyProjects\first_test\1stTest.robot': Setting variable 'Library' failed: Invalid variable name 'Library'.
```

The beginning of my script has nothing special, you can see it here:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is a simple robot example
Library        Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${SERVER}       http://google.com
${BROWSER}      Chrome
${DELAY}        0
```

I installed selenium2library using pip without any problem or message error. Still in my code when I write in PyCharm, on the first line `Documentation` is displayed in orange, however `Library` is displayed in different orange, like grayed out...

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Run the same on my machine and could not able to reproduce this error

Comment: yeah that makes sense :) should be a problem with mine...just need any clue on what to do or how to start fixing it

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means a single test case with the fewest number of settings and variables possible while still reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the above from one file and in that file EXACTLY how you have pasted above?  Is there more to it below perhaps including the text Library?

To my mind this error could only occur if you have Library in the variables section?  Is your settings section correct?  Perhaps some invalid syntax so it's not being properly considered?

Answer (score -2):

There should be only 1 space between Library and Selenium2Library. That should fix that